# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, ajax

I'm trying to submit my forms via ajax request , but now it makes crush and raise this error since i created my second ajax submition form :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

here is my first and second ajax submition form

```js
#first
const create_city_form = document.getElementById('create-city')
create_city_form.addEventListener("submit",submitCityHandler);
function submitCityHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/forms/cities',
        data : $('#create-city').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: successCityFunction,
        error:errorCityFunction,
    });
}
function successCityFunction(data,xhr) {
    if (data.success==true) {

        create_city_form.reset();                
        alertify.success('added')  
        
    }
}
function errorCityFunction(data,xhr){
    for(var key in data.responseJSON['error_msg']){
        if(key == 'city'){
            document.getElementById('city_name_error').removeAttribute('hidden')
            document.getElementById('city_name_error').innerHTML = data.responseJSON['error_msg'][key][0]

        }
    }

}

#second
const create_com_form = document.getElementById('create-com')
create_com_form.addEventListener("submit",submitCusComHandler);
function submitCusComHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/forms/companies',
        data : $('#create-com').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: successComFunction,
        error:errorComFunction,
    });
}
function successComFunction(data,xhr) {
    if (data.success==true) {
        create_com_form.reset();                     
        alertify.success('added')  
        
    }
}
function errorComFunction(data,xhr){
    for(var key in data.responseJSON['error_msg']){
        if(key == 'name'){
            document.getElementById('com_name_error').removeAttribute('hidden')
            document.getElementById('com_name_error').innerHTML = data.responseJSON['error_msg'][key][0]
        }


    }

}
```

```html
first form 
    <form action="" method="POST" id="create-city">{% csrf_token %}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>city name</label>
            {{form.city}}
          </div>
          <p class="text-danger text-center" hidden id="city_name_error"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">save</button>
     
    </form>

second form
            <form action="" method="POST" id="create-com">{% csrf_token %}        

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-tag"></i>
                    <label>company name</label>
                    {{ form.name }}
                    </div>
                    <p class="text-danger text-center" hidden id="com_name_error"></p>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <i class="fas fa-city"></i>
                    <label>city</label>
                    {{form.city | add_class:'select2bs4 form-control'}}
                    </div>
                    <p class="text-danger text-center" hidden id="city_cus_name_error"></p>
                </div>                                  
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">save</button>

        </form>
```

is there something i've missed please ?
when i remove one them the other works fine ! but together only the first one works ?!
what should i do to make both works without any problem please ?
thank you in advance ..

Comment: Have you tried creating separate templates for these to and extending them on top of one another?

Comment: @AaronCloud yes , i've created separate templates , but one file for the whole script

Comment: Is this error happening when submitting the second form? Find the request in the network tab of your dev tools, is the status code a 403? Do you get a CSRF error in your server logs?

Comment: When are you adding your eventListeners in relation to the DOM being created? It can't add an listener on an element that doesn't yet exist.

Comment: @IainShelvington yes , in second form , it return nothing in the network tab no status ! no error excep `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')`

Comment: @IainShelvington but it works find when i create separate js files

Comment: Try wrapping $(document).ready(function () {} around your js script. The issue is likely caused by parts of your script being executed before the respective DOM elements are created.

Comment: @yagus yes thank you fixed